# Bash script with command argument not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

Using a bash script `./find_dates`. Code in `find_dates`

```
 grep '^2019/02/01' /pi/home/data/*|sort -t: -k2 > /pi/home/files/data.txt;
```

I am getting data in the `data.txt`

However when I run `./find_dates2 2019/02/01`. Code in `find_dates2`:

```
grep '^$1' /pi/home/data/*|sort -t: -k2 > /pi/home/files/data.txt;
```

The `data.txt` is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple typo - use double quotes instead of single quotes, otherwise the variable doesn't get expanded.

```
grep "^$1" /pi/home/data/*|sort -t: -k2 > /pi/home/files/data.txt;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had that but I didn't think it was working.  But I was sending in the incorrect date.  Thank you.